# Why base class function is called instead of derived one?

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding

I have a class:

```
class ProjectService : public CProjectT<CSoapMSXMLInetClient>
{
...
}
```

I have implemented `HRESULT ConnectToServer();` function in this derived class. Then I instantiated an object and called a function:

```
ProjectService project;
project.f1();
```

now, `f1()` calls `f2()` and `f2()` calls `ConnectToServer()`. All of those functions are members of `CProjectT<CSoapMSXMLInetClient>`

The problem here is, `CProjectT<CSoapMSXMLInetClient>::ConnectToServer()` is called instead of `ProjectService::ConnectToServer()`. (I have a debug breakpoint on the first line of both `ConnectToServer()` functions. The one in base class is hit.)

Why?

Comment: Is the ConnectToServer function defined with the `virtual` keyword?

Comment: no, it is not. but i have the instance of derived class not base. i thought in that case derived function should be called

Comment: @Ali: it will be called, if ConnectToServer will be defined as virtual, otherwise the compiler won't even put it in the virtual table, and the base function will always be called.

Comment: @Ozair: you should put that comment (with a short explanation) as an answer

Comment: That's what virtual function is for.

Comment: am i missing a point here? why should there be the virtual table at all? i am not using any base class pointer, i just have an instance of derived class and not any pointer or reference to base class, but still base class function is called. that confuses me because i thought if you have an object itself of derived class, then derived functions will be called regardless of virtualness. am i wrong?

Comment: @Ali: f2() invokes ConnectToServer(), and the method is defined at COMPILE TIME. since f2() is a part of CProject and NOT ProjectService, so it have two possibilities: invoke hard coded a none virtual function from CProject OR invoke a function from the virtual table. since ConnectToServer() is not virtual, the first option will be 'chosen' by the compiler.

Comment: *"now, `f1()` calls `f2()` and `f2()` calls `ConnectToServer()`"* -- in addition to this textual description, your code should also demonstrate this relation. (And you can probably drop `f1()` from the chain by calling `f2()` directly.) Details of the declarations are relevant, and if you knew which details are relevant, you'd already know the answer.

Comment: @HayriUğurKoltuk *"i am not using any base class pointer"* -- unless `f2()` is declared `static`, then you *are* using a base class pointer, namely `this` (when calling `this->ConnectToServer()`, even if the `this->` part is not explicit in your code). Just an example of why code details are important and should supplement your textual description. (The overly-minimal code is also why I've decided to not VTC another question as a duplicate of this.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said, you need the keyword `virtual`. Why? Because in your function `f2()`, defined only in `CProjectT`, you call the function `CProjectT<CSoapMSXMLInetClient>::ConnectToServer()`. Without the `virtual` keyword, there is no way to know for `f2()` that the derived method should be called.

If you want to test :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base
{
public:
    void f(){g();} // Wants to call Base::g() if there's no "virtual" keyword
    void g(){cout << "Base" << endl;}
    // virtual void g(){cout << "Base" << endl;}
};
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    void g(){cout << "Derived" << endl;}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Derived d;
    d.f();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the ConnectToServer function is defined with the keyword `virtual` in the parent class.

Read about the [virtual keyword in C++](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/cplr139.htm)

Comment: the keyword virtual tells the compiler to put the method in class' virtual table. a virtual method will be invoked using a function pointer located in this table. this pointer was overrided by the derived class, and the derived method will be executed.

Comment: that makes perfect sense when I call functions with a base class pointer or reference. i would not be surprised. however, i call functions using a derived class instance(not reference or pointer, but value). at compile time, compiler knows that the object is an instance of derived class. doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

f2() invokes ConnectToServer(), and the method f2() is defined at **COMPILE TIME**. since f2() is a part of CProject and NOT ProjectService, it have two possibilities: 

1. invoke hard coded a none virtual function from CProject 

2. invoke a function from the virtual table.

since ConnectToServer() is not virtual, the first option will be 'chosen' by the compiler.

like @Ozair said in the first comment (and his answer): putting the virtual keyword will make the function virtual and the compiler will 'choose' the second option, and derived class will be called.

(note that the function is called from f2(), so the compiler can't really tell if this instance is the base or derived)