# calling function defined in base class

Tags: c++

I have two simple c++ classes:

```
class base {
protected:
  double a ;
public:
  double getValue(void) { return a ; }
  double getValue2(void) { return 2*this->getValue() ; }
} // end class base

class derived : public base {
private:
  double b ;
public:
  double getValue(void) { return a+b ; }
}  // end class derived
```

Then I call

```
  derived A ;
  A.getValue2() ;
```

The problem is, the method `getValue2()` calls the method `getValue()` from the base class (not the derived one). Is it possible to call in `getValue2()` function `getValue()` from the derived class or do I need to redefine `getValue2()` in the derived class?

Comment: You forgot the virtual keyword...

Comment: I think -5 is *really* harsh. If the OP comes from a Java background, this is wierd. The question is well written - contains a good code snippet - and documents the expected and actual output.

Comment: @Bathsheba if you google the question you get the answer

Comment: Please document the google search you used, so we can gauge the "obviousness".

Comment: @Bathsheba "why is function of derived class called instead of the one in base class" -> First hit is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6371929/why-base-class-function-is-called-instead-of-derived-one

Comment: @Bathsheba "c++ call derived method base class" on google.com

Comment: Point taken, and thanks for justifying. I'll keep my upvote on the question though, for its clarity.

Comment: @Bathsheba Totally agree. If all questions were like this one...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need to do is make `getValue` `virtual` in the base class:

```
virtual double getValue(void) { return a ; }
```

That function will be then be `virtual` through the entire class structure (there is no need to repeat the keyword in the child classes although some folk do so for clarity).

Unlike Java, `virtual`-ness is not automatic.

Comment: I'd suggest using **override** keyword in the derived method.

Comment: @peval27: Do feel free to submit an answer detailing that.

Comment: I can't since it's marked as duplicated! :D Please edit you answer though

Comment: I don't necessarily agree with using `override`!

Comment: If will be `double getValue(void) override { return a+b ; }`

Comment: @Bathsheba Why not? In this case (and obviously other cases too) it would have helped to identify a missing `virtual`. What would be the downside of `override`?

Answer (score 2):

Mark the base method as **virtual** and the derived method as **override**:

```
class base {
protected:
  double a ;
public:
  virtual double getValue(void) { return a ; }
  double getValue2(void) { return 2*this->getValue() ; }
};

class derived : public base {
private:
  double b ;
public:
  double getValue(void) override { return a+b ; }
};
```

Comment: This will not compile. Missing semicolons at the end of the class definitions for starters. Which makes me think the OP comes from Java.

Comment: @SimonKraemer I didn't have a compiler under my hands. now it's fixed